# MongoDb driver in nodejs does not call open function callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In the following code the function passed to the open function never runs, then the istruction console.log('open!') in the following code never runs:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var Db = mongo.Db;
var connection = mongo.Connection;
var Server = mongo.Server;

var client = new Db('test', new Server("localhost", 27017, {}));

var test = function (err, collection) {
    collection.insert({a:2}, function(err, docs) {

        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            test.assertEquals(1, count);
        });

        // Locate all the entries using find
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            test.assertEquals(1, results.length);
            test.assertTrue(results[0].a === 2);

            // Let's close the db
            client.close();
         });
    });
};

client.open(function(err, p_client) {
    console.log('open!');
    client.collection('test_insert', test);
});
```

From the log I see that the connection is accepted:

```
Sun March 11 16:52:01 [initandlisten] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:61875 # 1
```

Mongodb great works from interactive shell.

can someone tell me any suggestion?

thank you!

Comment: What version of Node are you using? And what version of node driver are you using?

Comment: further to your question I have upgraded to the latest version of node, I reinstalled the drivers and now everything works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste this...it should work without any problems:

```
var client = new Db('test', new Server("localhost", 27017, {}), {});
client.open(function(err, client) {
    console.log('open!');
}
```

Also, don't forget to authenticate after opening the connection.

```
var client = new Db('test', new Server("localhost", 27017, {}), {});
client.open(function(err, client) {
    console.log('open!');
    client.authenticate('admin', 'admin', function(err, result) {
        // Authenticated
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I have the same problem with this code

Comment: yes, it log 'asdf'. Instead open callback runs only if mondodb is off :(